# setOnClickListener and findByViewId

Tags: android

this part of my code is having a problem

```
insertButton = (Button) findByViewId(R.id.button1);  
insertButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener();
```

it keeps saying method undefined for findByViewId, method for setOnClickListener not applicable  and OnClickListener cannot be resolved
here is my full code

```
package edu.nyp.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddData extends Activity {
    Button insertButton = null;
    EditText shopText= null;
EditText dealText= null;
EditText locationText= null;
EditText websiteText= null;
EditText categoryText= null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adddata);

    insertButton = (Button) findByViewId(R.id.button1);
    insertButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            DBAdapter dbAdapter = new
                    DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            try{
                dbAdapter.open();

                String shop = shopText.getText().toString(); 
                String deal = dealText.getText().toString(); 
                String location = locationText.getText().toString(); 
                String website = websiteText.getText().toString(); 
                String category = categoryText.getText().toString(); 
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Add Data ", e.getMessage());
            }
            finally{
                if (dbAdapter != null)
                    dbAdapter.close();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.adddata, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

may i know what is wrong?

Comment: seems your forgot to import the interface: import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Answer (score 1):

Import below line in your activity

> ```
> import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `findViewById` method instead of `findByViewId`.

```
insertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
insertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       //Code for action listener.
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
insertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that i can find unusual about the above code is :

```
insertButton = (Button) findByViewId(R.id.button1);
```

So replace it with:

```
insertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

The rest of the code is fine. I mean the below code is perfectly fine:

```
 insertButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            DBAdapter dbAdapter = new
                    DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            try{
                dbAdapter.open();

                String shop = shopText.getText().toString(); 
                String deal = dealText.getText().toString(); 
                String location = locationText.getText().toString(); 
                String website = websiteText.getText().toString(); 
                String category = categoryText.getText().toString(); 
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Add Data ", e.getMessage());
            }
            finally{
                if (dbAdapter != null)
                    dbAdapter.close();
            }
        }
    });
```

The above kind of syntax always works for me.